# Manufacturer name in category of products in opencart

Tags: php, opencart, categories

I am trying to show manufacturer name in category product. adding following code show some

*error*

> "Undefined index: manufacturer_id in
>   C:\wamp\www\pcc\catalog\controller\product\category.php"

```
$this->load->model('catalog/manufacturer');
$manufacturer = $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getManufacturer($result['manufacturer_id']);
```

please give me some idea i want to show manufacturer name with each product in category page.

Comment: share the result.. `var_dump($result);` or `print_r($result);`

Comment: `$result['manufacturer_id']` its not defined, where is $result?? initilized??

Comment: [link]http://premiumcigarcompany.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=59

Comment: above link need to add manufacturer of the products. my code is not showing result but above error..

Comment: what is `$result`? is it `path=59` ??

Comment: i've added following `code`<?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
                     if($category
                     <span><?php echo $category['name']; ?></span>
                    <?php } ?>

Comment: it showed the id of every product. but i want to show manufacturer name of that id. echo manufacturer where id = $category['name']

Comment: not getting yur point, `print_r($result);` ? check this

Comment: it shows the array details of particular product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify the CORE of opencart or you should use OCMod.
something like `$this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getManufacturer($product_info['manufacturer_id']);` will return the manufacturer data. then you can retrieve what you want (image, name and...).

you can find the solution [here](https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=24796)
you can find some tutorial [here](https://isenselabs.com/posts/how-to-add-the-manufacturer-logo-to-your-product-page-in-opencart-2x) too, but it's about product page. for category page it's same.